# Please Help with this Boolean Expression Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been asked to simplify the following expression in an assignment problem:

X’YZ + XYZ + XY’Z’+XYZ’ + XY’Z’ + X’Y’Z’ + WX’Y’Z’ + W’X’Y’Z’

The result of the simplification should only be 2 terms. I have attempted many times and I have been only arriving at three terms at best. Below are my steps:

(X’ + X) YZ + (Y’+Y) XZ’ + (X + X’) Y’Z’ + (W + W’) X’Y’Z’

YZ + XZ’ + Y’Z’ + X’Y’Z’

YZ + (X + Y’) Z’ + X’Y’Z’

YZ + (X + Y’ + X’Y’) Z’

YZ + (X + Y’ (1 + X’)) Z’

YZ + (X + Y’) Z’

YZ + XZ’ + Y’Z’

I am not sure how to go 2 terms from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have repeated the term : $XY'Z'$ Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Yes. Below is the question word by word:

Simplify the given Boolean expression using the laws of Boolean logic. Show each simplification you
make and please include the name of the law you used (e.g. complementation, idempotent, etc.) If
you’re having trouble getting started, remember this is just like Algebra. Collect like terms and factor
them out of the logical expression the exact same way you would an algebraic equation. As a hint,
although it isn’t clear at first glance, the simplified expression contains just 2 terms!
X’YZ + XYZ + XY’Z’+XYZ’ + XY’Z’ + X’Y’Z’ + WX’Y’Z’ + W’X’Y’Z’

Comment: thanks for confirming! I too am (unfortunately) getting 3 terms..

Comment: @CluelessCoder your result is correct, there was probably a typo in the given expression.